# BeautifulSoup method find() is not applying on other attributes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

## Problems with attributes in BS4

Attributes set = with the BeautifulSoup Object do not have the same attributes as the BeautifulSoup Object.
I already red some of the Documentation and even copied some examples from YouTubers (just to be certain).
It just does not work.

I am trying to get some Information about the price etc. if that helps.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get data
data = requests.get('https://www.wg-gesucht.de/wg-zimmer-und-1-zimmer-wohnungen-in-Berlin.8.0+1.1.0.html?offer_filter=1&city_id=8&sort_column=3&noDeact=1&radLat=52.5381224&radLng=13.2602887&categories%5B%5D=0&categories%5B%5D=1&rent_types%5B%5D=0&radAdd=Nonnendammallee+104%2C+Berlin%2C+Deutschland%2C+13629&radDis=5000')

# load data into bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

# locates every listed flat
flat_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"col-sm-8 card_body"})
```

printing `flat_data[0]` works just fine

```
name = []
price = []
size = []

# goes through all flats and adds the price to the list (broke)
for flat in flat_data:
    name.append(flat_data.find("div",{"class":"co.-cs-5"}))
    #...
```

Error message after running the program above:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Everything you should know about how to solve your issue *is in the error message*. Also, you might greatly benefit from reading [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I think you meant flat instead of flat_data
    name.append(flat.find("div",{"class":"co.-cs-5"}))
    #...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flat_data` is of type `ResultSet` - it doesn't have method `.find`. You probably meant `flat.find(...)`.

To get name, price, size from this page, you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get data
data = requests.get(
    "https://www.wg-gesucht.de/wg-zimmer-und-1-zimmer-wohnungen-in-Berlin.8.0+1.1.0.html?offer_filter=1&city_id=8&sort_column=3&noDeact=1&radLat=52.5381224&radLng=13.2602887&categories%5B%5D=0&categories%5B%5D=1&rent_types%5B%5D=0&radAdd=Nonnendammallee+104%2C+Berlin%2C+Deutschland%2C+13629&radDis=5000"
)

# load data into bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")

# locates every listed flat
flat_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col-sm-8 card_body"})
for flat in flat_data:
    name = flat.h3["title"]
    price = flat.select_one(".col-xs-8, .col-xs-3").get_text(
        strip=True, separator=" "
    )
    size = flat.find("b", text=lambda t: t and "²" in t)
    size = size.text if size else "-"
    print("{:<60} {:<10} {}".format(name[:59], price, size))
```

Prints:

```
Keine Küche? Kredite vergleichen & sparen                    ab 540 €   -
Großes Zimmer für mehrere Monate in super Lage frei          ab 440 €   -
1 FURNISHED ROOM ON NICE FLAT IN FRIEDRICHSHAIN-KREUZBERG    475 €      24 m²
1 Zimmer frei, 2er Wg in Friedrichshain, 5-6 Monate , viell  425 €      17 m²
Large furnished bedroom in Lichtenberg flatshare             515 €      18 m²
Suche neue/n Mitbewohner/in zum 01.06.2021 für 2er WG (3-Zi  700 €      17 m²
Furnished room in a Fully Furnished Bright Apartment Ideal   600 €      23 m²
16. - 23.06.21 Ruhige möblierte 1-Zimmer-Wohnung             200 €      36 m²
2er WG in Kreuzberg                                          360 €      16 m²
"hübsches Altbauerkerzimmer im Zentrum der City West sehr g  595 €      26 m²
Sonniges Wg-Zimmer mit sehr guter Anbindung                  445 €      22 m²
Travekiez in Friedrichshain: 16 qm-Zimmer in 2er-WG mit vie  300 €      16 m²
Helles Studio mit Sonnen-Balkon                              1080 €     35 m²
All-inclusive, fully-furnished room with balcony in newly r  775 €      17 m²
 Studenten-WG in Dahlem sucht neuen Mitbewohner (Studente  250 €      15 m²
 Studenten-WG in Dahlem sucht neuen Mitbewohner (Studente  200 €      8 m²
Spacious room in cozy 3-bedroom flat in Kreuzberg!           850 €      18 m²
Large private room in shared apartment, all bills included   800 €      18 m²
Charming renovated studio in Neukölln                        880 €      36 m²
Private bedroom with balcony in a brand new Co-Living build  550 €      10 m²
Private bedroom in a brand new Co-Living building in Berlin  510 €      9 m²
Cozy room in spacious 2-bedroom flat with living room in We  700 €      14 m²
registration, perfect f. internship etc. wonderful Prenzlau  465 €      11 m²
```